# How to clear previous user cache data in Flutter Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am facing a problem of whenever a user signs out `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` and signs In with another account the previous user's data is visible. I have seen documentation and got an idea of clearing the cache data using  `FirebaseFirestore.clearPersistence()`. I tried this in the `signOut` method but though previous user's data is still visible. Can anyone please solve my issue!

> main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings=Settings(
    persistenceEnabled: false,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

> firebaseAuth.dart

```
  static logOut()async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
    return  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you mean by "the users data is still visible".  What are you doing to observe this?  How can we reproduce this on our own?

Comment: Did you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: In my case, i implemented Google sign in with firebase flutter. Signin and singout and every aspect of the app work excellent. But, When i want to switch to different sub account for google signin after signing out. Google popup doesnt appear until i clear the cache. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You probably fixed this already but I was having the same issue and what worked for me was clearing app variables when loggin out.

I created a function to clear the variables and called it right before the signOut method

Comment: can you give code example for how to clear the app variables before signout?

Comment: This works, but it seems weird that firebase been based on streams and a very accurate cache management by user, do this. Definitely the OP needs to give us more info on what was doing.

Comment: Can you give more, as what you exactly did! because clearing variables seems easy but i am facing issues.